# python for loop in os.walk()

Tags: python, loops, os.walk

i write this code to get the count of files inside my directory but i need it to count the output lines when it run ...

```
import os
for dir,subdir,files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test"):
    i = 0 
    i = i + 1 
    print(str(i) + ": files "+str(len(files)))
```

output :

```
1: files 3
1: files 0
1: files 0
```

the line number is does not change it's stay 1 ?? how i can solve it and explain why please i need to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are initializing i =0 in every iteration

```
import os
i = 0 
for dir,subdir,files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test"):
    i = i + 1 
    print(str(i) + ": files "+str(len(files)))
```

Answer (score 2):

this is pretty obvious as

```
i = 0 
i = i + 1
```

in a row is equivalent to

```
i = 1
```

Don't handle your indices yourself. Use `enumerate` instead, starting at 1, and since you're not using the dir parts, just anonymize them when unpacking.

```
for i,(_,_,files) in enumerate(os.walk(r"C:\Users\adam\Desktop\test"),1):
    print("{} : files ".format(i,len(files)))
```